# udp Stop-and-Wait acks not working

Tags: java, udp

I am trying to implement a UDP Stop-and-Wait protocol. I have managed to get my UDP Sender and Receiver successfully transfer an image file. Now I am trying to implement ACKs.

When my sender finishes sending a packet it waits for the receiver to send an ACK. The receiver sends an ACK once it has received a packet from the sender.
Here is the code in the sender which waits for an ACK:
where `seqNum` is the packet number the sender just sent to the receiver and the `sendPacket` is the packet just sent. I add this as a parameter in case the sender needs to resend it.

```
private static void receiveACK(int seqNum, DatagramPacket sendPacket) throws IOException {
        byte[] ack = new byte[2];
        boolean received = false;
        int recSeqNum = -1;
        ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(ack);
        DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(bais);
        DatagramPacket receivePacket = new DatagramPacket(ack, ack.length);
        while(!received) {
            try {
                clientSocket.setSoTimeout(50);
                clientSocket.receive(receivePacket);
                recSeqNum = dis.readShort();
                System.out.println("ACK: " + ack );
            } catch (SocketTimeoutException e) {
                System.out.println("Timed out: Still waiting for ACK");
            }
            System.out.println(recSeqNum);
            if(recSeqNum == seqNum) {
                received = true;
            } else {
                clientSocket.send(sendPacket);
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is the code in the receiver that sends an ACK:

```
private static void sendACK(int seqNum, InetAddress returnAddress) throws IOException {
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(baos);
        dos.writeShort(seqNum);
        dos.flush();
        System.out.println("send: " + seqNum);
        byte[] sendArray = baos.toByteArray();
        DatagramPacket sendPacket = new DatagramPacket(sendArray, sendArray.length, returnAddress, port );
        receieverSocket.send(sendPacket);
    }
```

The problem is that the receiver just constantly tries to send the first packet and the sender just times out.

Both sender and receiver are on the same machine.

Comment: What does the traffic flow look like in wireshark?

Comment: I am using Windows, is there a way of using Wireshark on localhost in Windows?

Comment: I haven't tried that specifically but I would be very surprised if it didn't Just Work.